Set "cache-control: max-age" header for GeoServer tiles globally
When I use GeoServer (GeoWebCache) tiles with default settings, they are coming with response header
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

I am trying to set it to
cache-control: max-age=3600

I managed to do it for a single layer in its tile caching settings. I would like to do it globally for all existing layers or at least set default value of max tile age for all newly created layers or layergroups.
I also use REST API, so if it's possible to set it this way, I'd be happy with that.

I finally did it via REST API.
What I needed was to set expireClients parameter and update existing GWC layers with PUT request.
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/api/#1.0.0/gwclayers.yaml
